# Анимация по нажатию кнопки в UI

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть кнопка на экране, необходимо по нажатию кнопки изменить анимацию игрока. Не могу понять как привязать элемент анимации в скрипте кнопки
`

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class Button1 : MonoBehaviour {
    public PlayerController Bing;

    private GameObject Dang;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        Dang = GameObject.Find("Player");
        Dang.GetComponent<Animation>();




    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0) Dang.GetComponent<Animation>(animation{ } ) ;


    }
}
```

`

Comment: Какая версия юнити? У вас humanoid( используйте аниматор https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/Manual/Animator.html  ) или generic/legacy анимации( https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/Manual/AnimationScripting.html ) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создайте в контроллере игрока отдельный метод public в котором будете выполнять переключение анимации для персонажа. А далее все просто, в UI кнопки добавляется обработчик события на нажатие и в нем вызываете метод чтобы сменить анимацию.